# Returning a function call?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is this:

```
def outer(x):
    def inner():
        print x
    return inner

>>> outer("foo")()
```

The same as this:

```
def outer(x):
    def inner():
        print x
    return inner()

>>> outer("foo")
```

Both work, but is there a more pythonic way to write something like this?

Comment: They  do different things.  The first returns a function, the second returns `None`.  A function returning a function is a common technique in languages that have first order functions.  And a function inside another one strictly to help the outer function (an inner function) is also quite common -- often to prevent namespace bloat or clarify the program functionality / intent.

Comment: @wim, my comment was hardly worthy of a *real* answer, but I appreciate your concern...

Answer (score 3):

Neither is "more pythonic" in absolute terms, because you would use them in different circumstances.

Returning a function to be called later is appropriate if you're generating a callback to be wired up somewhere else, closing over some inputs (with others to be filled in later), or for similar advanced use cases.

Returning a value or immediately performing a side-effecting action is appropriate if your callers will only be interested in that value or action, and you don't have any particular reason to split the operation into stages.

Answer (score 0):

They are different. In your example, the first will return a function, that you can use later, and the second will return None type, because you're returning nothing, just printing x.